# what should be the primitive type of an integer with size 9bytes or more than 9 bytes?

Tags: java

I am creating a bank account.which has a 'accnum' as variable.which has integer value with size of 12 bytes.
let say the bank account number is  180020131111.How do you initialize to a variable?

```
public class number{ 
   public static void main(String[] args){
       private long x=180020131111; // is not working.. 
       System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: use `private long x=180020131111l;`. Notice the lowercase `L` at the end.

Comment: you can also use string for those numerical looking fields where you don't perform any mathematical calculations

Comment: Long is a really wrong datatype here, the actions you would do (display, validate, leading zeroes..) all require you to use a string for it. It doesn't make any sense to perform arithmetic with bank account numbers.

Comment: You cannot have `public/protected/private` modifiers while declaring a variable in a method.

Answer (score 5):

`180020131111` is an integer literal, which cannot fit into an `int` type. You should append an `L` at the end to make it `long` literal.

```
private long x = 180020131111L;
```

Well, I would rather store account number as String. I don't think there is really any need for storing it as numeral, as you are just going to display it. I mean it would really look weird if you are going to do some arithmetic operations on account numbers.

Comment: though it looks weird.I am going to do arithmetic operation.. as account numbers should be sequential..

Answer (score 1):

By default Integral Literals are treated as 32 bit `int` and not 64 bit `long` in java..

Use this

```
private long x=180020131111L;
```

The character `l` ot `L` at the end makes integral literals long

Answer (score 1):

The largest Java primitive integral type is `long` which is a 64 bit (8 byte) signed type.  If you want to represent numbers larger that 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 == 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, you need to use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`.

---

The problem with this statement ...

```
    private long x=180020131111;
```

... is that you are using the syntax for an `int` literal.  A `long` literal requires a `l` or `L` suffix.  (FWIW - this number does not require 9 bytes to represent ...)